# Obscuring jQueryUI Tabs content

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery

I have been working with the jQuery UI Tab component, and have successfully implemented loading the content for each tab via ajax.  Each tab calls a common php page with a get variable, which is then parsed by the common page to identify and echo the page content.

The problem I face is preventing a user from linking directly to this common php page, which will load the page content in a blank browser window... outside of the tab.  I have tried detecting the $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] to only load content when coming from a remote site, but this has several drawbacks, namely the back button and local page links.  There must certainly be a cleaner way.

Hopefully I'm missing something simple, but how can I force ajax content to be viewed in a tab on a given page, rather than sidestepping the tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to stop it 100% of the time, but you could stop most people from non-ajax access with:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    // it's an ajax request
}
```

Keep in mind that headers can be spoofed easily so this is by no means secure but it will take care of most requests just fine.

Comment: I'm not worried about spoofing, just the general day-to-day visitors.  However, after further testing it appears that IE9 on Win7 doesn't pass this header, while all other browsers under Mac and Windows send it.   Oh well, another IE workaround... back to the drawing board.

Comment: IE workarounds are an unfortunate way of life sometimes :) You could pass something on the query string, like `?ajax=1`. Not the prettiest solution but it may be enough for what you're doing.